# Hiding rows based on cell value in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide all blank rows until the value "stop" is detected.

I get a Overflow error message when the code reaches `Entirerow.hidden = True`.

```
Dim Count as Integer
Count = 0
Dim Rge as Range
Set Rge = Sheets("ForPrint").Range("b24").Offset(count,0)

Do Until Rge.Value = "Stop"

    If Rge.Value = "" Then
        Rge.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End if

    Count = Count + 1

Loop
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much.  I used the second option but the first one looks much more elegant.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are not setting the range in Loop:

This simple loop will do the Job:

```
Dim Rge As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set Rge = Sheets("ForPrint").Range("B:B").Find("Stop")

For Each cl In Sheets("ForPrint").Range("B24:B" & Rge.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Next
```

Otherwise in your code Try this:

```
Dim Count As Integer
Count = 0
Dim Rge As Range

Set Rge = Sheets("ForPrint").Range("b24").Offset(Count, 0)

Do Until Rge.Value = "Stop"

Set Rge = Sheets("ForPrint").Range("b24").Offset(Count, 0)
If Rge.Value = "" Then
Rge.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

Count = Count + 1

Loop
```